# Measurability of randomly chosen coordinate

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space, and
$$f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n, f(\omega)=(f_1(\omega),\ldots,f_n(\omega))$$ be measurable with respect to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal A.$

Additionally, let $a:\Omega\to\{1,\ldots, n\}$ be measurable w.r.t $\mathcal A$ (so not necessarily w.r.t $\mathcal F$). I am interested in the measurability of the map
$$f_{a}:\Omega\to\mathbb R$$
defined by $f_{a}(\omega)=f_{a(\omega)}(\omega).$ In particular, I want to prove (or disprove) that it is $\mathcal F$-measurable. What I have collected so far is that

- $f_i$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable for all $1\leq i\leq n.$
- We can define the projection $\pi:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to C(\mathbb R ^n,\mathbb R)$ such that $$(\pi(i))(f)(\omega)=f_i(\omega).$$ For all $1\leq i\leq n,$ $\pi(i)$ is continuous (this is more or less another formulation of the above point).
- We thus need to study the measurability of
  $$g:=(\pi(a))(f):\Omega\to\mathbb R.$$
- But $\pi(a(\omega))$ is a continuous function for all $\omega,$ so that $g$ is the composition of an $\mathcal F$-measurable function with a continuous function.

From there, I am tempted to conclude that $g$ is $\mathcal F$ measurable. However, my intuition tells me that it cannot be, since $a$ is not necessarily $\mathcal F$-measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=2$, $f_1 \equiv 0$ and $f_2 \equiv 1$. It is clear that $f$ is measurable w.r.t. **every** sigma algebra.

But $g_n = 1_{\{a(\omega) =2\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if and only if $a$ is.

Comment: Seems like a perfect and simple counter example.